# apply associativity in CafeOBJ

Tags: functional-programming

I need (as a part of larger proof) to proove that a * (b * c) equals (a * b) * c which is true because * is declared associative.
I can *match* one term with another but it is not what I need because I need to write a proof score in form

```
start
...
close
```

so I need to use *apply* or something like.

What I've tried is to mark associativity as an axiom:

```
eq [assoc] : x:Elt * (y:Elt * z:Elt) = (x * y) * z .
```

but I cannot *apply* it then either because I cannot substitue multiple arguments

```
%MONOID> show term

(c * (a * b)):Elt

%MONOID> apply -.assoc with x = a y = b z = c at term .

[Error] no successful parse
[Error]:
```

or maybe because this rule is marked as invalid (what is reported while applying other rules ):

```
** id-completion for rule: eq [assoc]: (x:Elt * (y:Elt * z:Elt)) = ((x * y) * z)

  -- Generated rules:
  none
  -- Generated, but invalid rules:
  eq [assoc]: (x:Elt * (y:Elt * z:Elt)) = ((x * y) * z)
```

how to apply associativity and how to apply equation with multiple arguments (cant find this in docs http://cafeobj.org/files/reference-manual.html#apply http://cafeobj.org/files/manual.pdf ) ?

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, the user cannot *directly* apply associativity that has been defined as an attribute of an operation. It seems that the system will apply associativity automatically. As an example of using associativity in a proof consider the `GROUP` module below. The axioms in the `GROUP` module are for the left part of a group theory specification. Associatitivity is specified as an attribute on the operation signature of `+`. Suppose the we wish to prove that the right inverse equation holds.

```
mod* GROUP {
[ G ]
op 0 : -> G .
op _+_ : G G -> G { assoc } 
op -_ : G -> G 
var X : G 
eq[left-identity] : 0 + X = X .
eq[left-inverse] : (- X) + X = 0 .
}
```

From  `GROUP` we can prove that for all `a` the equation `a + (- a) = 0` holds (right inverse). Equations are applied to terms and if the term matches an equation it is replaced with the other side of the equation.

```
set print mode fancy on
open GROUP .
op a : -> G .
start a + ( - a ) .
apply -.left-identity at (1) .
apply -.left-inverse with X = - a at (1 1) . 
apply red  at [2 .. 3] .  -- Associativity used: see proof output and show module
apply reduce at term .
--> Proof Output
result 0 + a + - a : G
result - (- a) + - a + a + - a : G
result - (- a) + 0 + - a : G
result 0 : G
```

The `show` command shows the details of a module

```
show module
```

Considering the axioms only, the output of the `show` command shows the current axioms of the proof score.

```
eq [left-identity]: 0 + X = X .
eq [left-identity_ext_A-m]: A2 + 0 + X + A1 = A2 + X + A1 .
eq [left-identity_ext_A-r]: 0 + X + A1 = X + A1 .
eq [left-identity_ext_A-l]: A1 + 0 + X = A1 + X .
eq [left-inverse]: - X + X = 0 .
```

We can see that the system has generated a set of associative axioms
involving identity.

**Conclusion**

The `apply` command applies a rewrite rule to a term. The builtin `{asscoc}` attribute cannot be directly applied to a term, rather associativity is applied by the system. If you define associativity as an equation it can be applied directly by the user, but proofs are usually longer.

The application of your user written associativity equation would parse if commas were added between the variable assignments:

```
mod* ASSOC{
[Elt]
op _*_ : Elt Elt -> Elt
eq [assoc] : x:Elt * (y:Elt * z:Elt) = (x * y) * z .
}
```

The equation can be directly applied in both directions. First apply the left hand side of the `[assoc]` equation to the term.

```
   open ASSOC .
    ops a b c : -> Elt .
    start c * (a * b) .
    apply .assoc at term .
    close
```

Next apply the right hand side of equation to the term.

```
open ASSOC .
ops a b c : -> Elt .
start (a * b) * c .
apply -.assoc with x = a, y = b, z = c at term  .
```